# S3PutObjectRequest and pre-signed URL

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, afnetworking

I would like to generate a pre-signed URL on my server to give users the ability to upload a specific file. I know how to do this and my server can return a pre-signed URL to my mobile app:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLZXXL76T4NQIMBQ&Expires=1395783022&Signature=dymvOAjnyebcbv%2BB7xR0g4UoqXQ%3D
```

I would then like to upload the file to S3. I was planning on using `S3PutObjectRequest` but it doesn't take a URL as a parameter.

I suppose I could use a regular `NSURLRequest` but I'm afraid I would loose some optimization that `S3PutObjectRequest` would offer for large files.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You can put object by pre signed url.